# startActivity sending to wrong activity: Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have it to where after the my "Overview" Button is clicked the next button "Variables" is enabled. The button enables, however the setOnClickListener for my "Variables" sends me to my OverviewActivity, rather than my VariablesActivity. I've been stuck on this for a while.

The Variables Activity is just a multiple choice screen, but i was just setting it up.

I'm really new to Java and Android Studio, so this is getting confusing fast

Code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button signOutBtn;
public Button overviewBtn;
public Button varBtn;
FirebaseAuth auth;
boolean overviewDone;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    signOutBtn = findViewById(R.id.signOutBtn);
    overviewBtn = findViewById(R.id.overviewBtn);
    varBtn = findViewById(R.id.varBtn);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    overviewDone = false;

    signOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            auth.signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    overviewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent overviewBtnIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, OverviewActivity.class);
            startActivity(overviewBtnIntent);
        }
    });

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("state")) {
        if (getIntent().getStringExtra("state").equals("enable")) {
            overviewDone = true;
            varBtn.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            varBtn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        varBtn.setEnabled(false);
    }

    varBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent varbiesButtonIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, VariablesActivity.class);
            startActivity(varbiesButtonIntent);
            Log.i("Variable Button", "Going to Variable Activity");
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
public class OverviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button backBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);

    backBtn = findViewById(R.id.ov_backButton);

    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(OverviewActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("state", "enable");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
public class VariablesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public RadioGroup radioGroup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_variables);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);

    // getting value of radio button checked
    final String value = ((RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();


    if(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1){
        // no radio buttons checked
    } else{
        // one the radio buttons are checked
        Log.i("Radio Button Clicked", value);
    }
}
```

}

Stacktrace:

```
2021-11-22 21:45:23.550 4535-4535/com.example.codehorizonapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.codehorizonapplication, PID: 4535
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.codehorizonapplication/com.example.codehorizonapplication.VariablesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.codehorizonapplication.VariablesActivity.onCreate(VariablesActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your app doesn't crash and therefore just shows the last activity again?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Yeah I think so, basically, when i click the button, the first time it goes to the overview activity, but then then when i click the variables button again it crashes.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash that happens after the second click? And can you post the `VariablesActivity`

Comment: @avalerio I edited it, I didnt know what a stacktrace was but after looking into i think it was what i posted

Answer (score 0):

```
int checkedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
String value = "";
if(checkedId != -1){
   value = ((RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId)).getText().toString();
}
```

`radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` returns -1 if there is nothing checked, -1 isn't a valid Id thus `findViewById` returns null.

`null.getText()` is a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

This is under the assumption that there is nothing selected and the fact that calling `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` doesn't crash only when you call `getText()` does it crash means your `radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);` is correct.

The reason the `OverviewActivity` is created instead is due to a stack problem caused by the premature end to `VariablesActivity` due to the exception.

Comment: after putting your code in, I'm still getting the same stacktrace error, is it that the '1' in the code should be something else maybe?

Comment: I corrected it, it should have been negative -1, like in my explanation.